# how to pass json object as one of the parameter in args to chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

How to pass json object as one of the parameters to chaincode function arguments while invoking in hyperledger fabric.
I have tried this and it comes out to be [Object, Object] with stub.getArgs() method

Answer (score 1):

While calling chaincode method from NodeSDK, pass the json object as a json string using 
[JSON.stringify](https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_json_stringify.asp) method.

When you received a json string as a parameter in chaincode, deserislize it in golang object (following is sample code)

```
function, args := helper.Stub.GetFunctionAndParameters()

var jsonObj interface{}

err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(args[0]), &jsonObj)
if err != nil {
   fmt.Println("Can't deserialize", []byte(args[0]))
}
```

Note : above code will deserialize anonymous json string. If you already know your json structure then first make a same json structure by using [golang struct](https://gobyexample.com/structs) and then deserialize your json string into object of that struct.

Answer (score 0):

Should pass as a string (e.g. string containing json data). From there, you can convert to json using `JSON.parse(string)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any third party Rest APIs to invoke/query the ledger , you can convert the object to base64 encoded string and decode it in chaincode.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check if the JSON sent is valid.

2) You have to convert your json object to **escape** json object to pass as an argument.

this [online tool](https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html#ad-output) will help in converting json object to escaped/ unescaped json.

Unescaped JSON :

```
[
{  
    "employee": {  
        "name":       "tom",   
        "salary":      56000,   
        "married":    "toJerry"  
    }  
},
{  
    "employee": {  
        "name":       "hem",   
        "salary":      56000,   
        "married":    "singleForever"
    }  
}
]
```

Escaped JSON :

```
[{\"employee\":{\"name\":\"tom\",\"salary\":56000,\"married\":\"toJerry\"}},{\"employee\":{\"name\":\"hem\",\"salary\":56000,\"married\":\"singleForever\"}}]
```

which is same as JSON.stringify(object)